# ASP.NET MVC: How to get notified about updates or events incoming in near future?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cron, signalr, periodic-task

I have a software system which users can submit reservation requests through web api using mobile applications.

I have a dashboard on web, implemented in  ASP.NET MVC and I want to inform operator about incoming reservations **(but near the time of reservation for example 30 minutes before reservation time)**.

I want to know are there any mechanism such as CronJobs or other stuff like this which can periodically checks the incoming reservations or not? I know about SignalR but it does not do periodical checks and it announce about real-time event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quarz to manage jobs and schedules:
https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

In case of pushing notifications, FireBase is also a great choice.